# Find $P(X\ge1|X\le6)$ from the cdf

Tags: discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

> $$\begin{array}{c|c}
> X\in&(-\infty,0)&[0,1)&[1,2)&[2,3)&[3,4)&[4,5)&[5,6)&[6,\infty)\\\hline
> F_X=&0&0.06&0.19&0.39&0.67&0.92&0.97&1\end{array}$$
> Find $P(X\ge1|X\le6)$.

This is the Question
but I'm confused because most my friends do this
$$P=\frac{P(1\le X\le6)}{P(X\le6)}=0.94$$
and I do this

[image: mine]

Whom one is doing it right and why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1\leq X\leq 6$ includes the point on the boundary ($X=1$), so you must exclude only $X<1$, rather than $X\leq 1$.

Thus your denominator should be:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(1\leq X\leq 6)&=\mathsf P(X\leq 6)-\mathsf P(X<1)\\&= F_X(6)-F_X(1^-)&&F_X(x^-):=\lim\limits_{a\nearrow x}F_X(a)\\&=1-0.06\\&=0.94\end{align}$$

Or, if you prefer: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{\,\in\,}[1,6])&=\mathsf P(X{\,\in\,}(-\infty,6]{\,\smallsetminus\,}(-\infty,1))\\&=1-0.06\\&=0.94\end{align}$$

Comment: ohhh I forgot to put it on Number Line to check it and your answer make it understanding even more ( even though it is kinda obvious that P(X≤6) - P(X>1) include 1 ( at first I didn't try to understand the meaning much so I didn't notice ). 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You both use the same correct formula for the conditional probability, but you calculated $F(1)$ incorrectly so you have to fix that.

Comment: But isn't F(1) supposed to be f(0) + f(1) which is 0.19?

Comment: If F(6) = 1 is right then why is F(1) = 0.19 is wrong?

Comment: @WWoPPoWW Because it should not be $F(1)$ but $\lim\limits_{x\nearrow 1} F(x)$,

Comment: so it should be coming to 1 from the left? Thanks!